# How do I delete a TStringGrid row?

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I have a TStringGrid, and I want to delete the selected row. Basic things I've tried only delete the *last* row. How do I delete an arbitrary row?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the code you've tried only deletes the last row, then you're probably just decrementing the `RowCount` property. That indeed always makes its modifications on the *end* of the list of rows. With that in mind, you could write code to ensure that the row you no longer want is the one at the end, and *then* delete the last row. (The most direct way would be to *move* the row, and there's a `MoveRow` method, but it's protected. If you wish to call protected methods, though, you may as well just [call `DeleteRow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352088/33732) instead.)

Using only public and published members, it's possible to write a loop that deletes an arbitrary row. For example, here's some code inspired by [Scalabium Software's FAQ on this topic](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0057.htm):

```
procedure DeleteRow(Grid: TStringGrid; ARow: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := ARow to Grid.RowCount - 2 do
    Grid.Rows[i].Assign(Grid.Rows[i + 1]);
  Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount - 1;
end;
```

It copies the contents of each row *below* the one you wish to delete into the row above. At the end of the loop, the row you wish to delete has been overwritten (by the row immediately below it) and there are two copies of the final row. Then it simply deletes the final row.

To delete the current row of the grid, call the function like this:

```
DeleteRow(Grid, Grid.Row);
```

Comment: To add, if you need only objects (like myself, dynamically drawing data in cells from the object instead of cell contents), then replace the second line with `Grid.Objects[0, I]:= Grid.Objects[0, I + 1];`. This is a bit speedier than replacing the entire contents which aren't even in use.

Answer (score 10):

The selected row of the grid is given by its `Row` property.

`TCustomGrid` has a `DeleteRow` method, but it's protected, so you can't call it except from within descendants of that class. It's easy to circumvent that restriction, though. Declare a `TCustomGrid` descendant, and then type-cast your grid control to that new type. Call `DeleteRow` on the result.

```
type
  TCustomGridAccess = class(TCustomGrid) end;

procedure DeleteGridRow(g: TCustomGrid; row: Integer);
begin
  TCustomGridAccess(g).DeleteRow(row);
end;
```

This works because in Delphi, members with protected visibility are implicitly *public* within the same unit as the class's declaration. Although `TCustomGrid` is declared in the *Grids* unit, our `TCustomGridAccess` class is declared in *your* unit, so your unit has access to all its protected methods, including `DeleteRow`.

---

If your Delphi version is new enough, then you can use a *class helper*. Class helpers can access protected members and don't require type-casting to technically unrelated types.

```
type
  TCustomGridHelper = class helper for TCustomGrid
  public
    procedure DelRow(ARow: Integer);
  end;

procedure TCustomGridHelper.DelRow(ARow: Integer);
begin
  Self.DeleteRow(ARow);
end;
```

Then, simply use the unit where you've declared the helper. Any descendant of `TCustomGrid` will automatically have a `DelRow` method, which you can call just like any other grid method:

```
grid.DelRow(grid.Row);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately I cannot find the DeleteRow in FireMonkey TCustomGrid (FMX.Grid). Am I correct? Or did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to Firemonkey because I didn't find ROWS functionality:

```
procedure TMainForm.StringGridDeleteRow(Grid: TStringGrid;
  ARow: integer);
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i := ARow to Grid.RowCount - 2 do
    for j := 0 to Grid.ColumnCount-1 do
        Grid.Cells[j,i] := Grid.Cells[j, i+1];
  Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount - 1;
end;
```